# Parameters pack not expanded with '...' even though ... is used

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers, function-call

I am currently trying to create an event template class for my engine.

My event class has an `std::vector<T>` where `T` is going to be defined as a *pointer to function* where the event is needed.

When calling the event it will call every function that was added to the vector with the necessary arguments.

Problem is when trying to compiling this part of the code for calling the event.

At the moment it is written like this.

```
template <typename... Args>
void Call(Args ... args)
{
   for (T f : functions)
   {
      f->*(args...);
   }
}
```

Note that I have tried :

```
f->*((args), ...);
f->*(std::forward(args)...);
f->*(args)...;
```

and many other similar solutions.

Every time I tried to compile the code I ran into:

```
include/event.h:71:22: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘...’ token
             f->*(args...);
                      ^
include/event.h:71:26: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
             f->*(args...);
```

I really don't understand the problem here.

Comment: Why not `f(args...)`? `->*` is for member function pointers.

Comment: it was originally written like that but it gave me this error:

include/event.h:71:14: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘f (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* f) (...)’
             f(args...);

Comment: Is `T` a function pointer or a member function pointer? These two are different.

Comment: The message told you to put `->*` on the left side of `f`. It should be something like `(object_ptr->*f)(args...);` or `(object.*f)(args...);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of calling a *function pointer* and *member function pointer* with arguments are different.

In case of a *function pointer*(i.e. free functions), you might do

```
f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

In the case of a *member function pointer*, you need an object(or pointer to an object) to invoke the member function, with its arguments.

```
(pointer_to_object->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

---

However, if you have access to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), just use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), which has suitable overloads for handling the cases mentioned above.

```
#include <utility>    // std::forward
#include <functional> // std::invoke

template <typename... Args>
void Call(Args&& ... args)
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --> also forwarding reference here
{
   for (T f : functions)
   {
      std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);  // like this
   }
}
```

Comment: sadly i have no access to c++17 at the moment, might try to change this later if it will help but i am currently writing using c++ 11

Comment: Yeah, you were right, my problem was misreading.
However i have another question: 
  If my pointer to function is already given with the object that invokes the function why does it require it again?
I'll try to explain myself better:

when i create my event i'll create it like this: 
 typedef void (Actor::*Collision)(std::shared_ptr<class engine::Collider> other_collider);
    Event<Collision*> OnCollision;

I'll then add a listener to the event like this: 

BoxCollider->OnCollision.AddListener(this->OnCollision);

I'm sorry for the dumb question, kinda new to this part

Comment: What do you mean again? Where? A member function has a hidden `this` argument, which needs to be provided using special syntax.

Comment: @MassimoIsonni **Firstly:** Did the answer helped you out to solve the current issue? if yes, you can [do the followings](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). **Secondly:**  *" However i have another question:"* this means, you [should be asking it seperatly in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). BTW, the comment what you wrote was not helping to understand your problem. Therefore, kinldy explian with a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).